# Apache 2.4.16 fails to start in XAMPP stack "No space left on device: AH01760: failed to initialize shm"

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, xampp

At first everything appears to work fine; running `sudo lampp start` prints

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-4...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

However apache seems to stop right away, as running `lampp status` right after `lampp start` prints:

```
Version: XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-4
Apache is not running.
cat: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/hostname.pid: Permission denied
MySQL is running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

Looking in `/opt/lampp/logs/error_log` shows:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 7861] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[ssl:warn] [pid 7861] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[suexec:notice] [pid 7861] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[auth_digest:notice] [pid 7862] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[auth_digest:error] [pid 7862] (28)No space left on device: AH01762: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /opt/lampp/logs/authdigest_shm.7862
[auth_digest:error] [pid 7862] (28)No space left on device: AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking, one-time nonces, and MD5-sess algorithm disabled
[:emerg] [pid 7862] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

There is lots of available disk space as far as I can tell, and I have plenty of free memory.
What is causing this error?

---

I've read some things about apache not clearing out semaphore arrays, but this doesn't seem to be the problem in my case; `ipcs -s` returns:

```
------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     
0xcbc384f8 294912     gandalf3   600        1         
0x0056a4d5 1966081    gandalf3   660        1
```